How to evaluate this integral : $I=\int^1_{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x)(5x^2+7)}}dx$
How to evaluate this integral :
$$I=\int^1_{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x)(5x^2+7)}}dx$$
$$I=\int^1_{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x)(5x^2+7)}}dx=\int^1_{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x)(5x^2+7)}}dx$$
Therfore:
$$2I =\int^1_{-1} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(5x^2+7)}}dx = 2 \int^1_{0} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(5x^2+7)}}dx $$
I need help evaluating this integration, thanks for your interest.

Looks like an elliptic integral. If you aren’t already familiar with those, then you’re probably in store for a huge headache.

You might find the generalized integral in the "Handbook of Elliptical Integrals"

$$ 
\begin{align} 
\color{red}{I} 
&=\int\limits_{-1}^{+1}\left[\, (1+x)\left(7+5x^2\right) \,\right]^{\small-\frac{1}{2}}\,dx \\[1mm]
&\quad\color{blue}{{\small\text{Substitute}}\left\{{\small x=t-1}\right\}} \\[1mm] 
&=\int\limits_{0}^{2}\left[\, 12-10x+5x^2 \,\right]^{\small-\frac{1}{2}}\,\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} \\[1mm] 
&\quad\color{blue}{{\small\text{Substitute}}\left\{{\small x=2t}\right\}} \\[1mm] 
&={\small\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}} \int\limits_{0}^{1}\left[\, \frac{3}{5}-x+x^2 \,\right]^{\small-\frac{1}{2}}\,\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} \\[1mm] 
&\quad\color{blue}{{\small\text{Factorize}}\left\{{\small 3/5-x+x^2}\right\}} \\[1mm] 
&={\small\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}} \int\limits_{0}^{1}\left[ \left({\small\frac{1-i\sqrt{7/5}}{2}}-x\right) \left({\small\frac{1+i\sqrt{7/5}}{2}}-x\right) \right]^{\small-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} \\[1mm] 
&\quad\color{blue}{{\small\text{Substitute}}\left\{{\small x=t^2}\right\}} \\[1mm] 
&={\small\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\frac{2}{1-i\sqrt{7/5}}} \int\limits_{0}^{1}\left[ \left(1-\frac{{\small2}x^2}{{\small1-i\sqrt{7/5}}}\right) \left({\small\frac{1+i\sqrt{7/5}}{1-i\sqrt{7/5}}} -\frac{{\small2}x^2}{{\small1-i\sqrt{7/5}}}\right) \right]^{\small-\frac{1}{2}}{dx} \\[1mm] 
&\quad\color{blue}{{\small\text{Substitute}}\left\{{\small x=t{\big/}\sqrt{\frac{2}{1-i\sqrt{7/5}}}}\right\}} \\[2mm] 
&={\small\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+i\sqrt{7/5}}}} \,\int\limits_{0}^{{\small\sqrt{\frac{2}{1-i\sqrt{7/5}}}}} \left[ \left(1-x^2\right) \left(1-{\small\frac{1-i\sqrt{7/5}}{1+i\sqrt{7/5}}}x^2\right) \right]^{\small-\frac{1}{2}}{dx} \\[1mm] 
&\quad\color{blue}{{\small\text{Elliptic Integral of 1st Kind}} \left\{{\small F\left[\,\phi,k\,\right]= \int\limits_{0}^{\sin\phi}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}}}\right\}} \\[2mm] 
&={\small\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+i\sqrt{7/5}}}}\, \,F\left[\arcsin\left({\small\sqrt{\frac{2}{1-i\sqrt{7/5}}}}\right), {\small\frac{1-i\sqrt{7/5}}{1+i\sqrt{7/5}}}\right] \\[4mm] 
&=\color{red}{{\small\sqrt{\frac{2}{6}\left(1-i\sqrt{7/5}\right)}}\, \,F\left[\arcsin{\small\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{6}\left(1+i\sqrt{7/5}\right)}\right),\, -\frac{1}{6}\left(1+i\sqrt{35}\right)}\right]} \\[4mm] 
&\color{blue}{\approx 0.938186} 
\end{align} 
$$

Thanks Maple CAS:
$$F(x)=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x+1\right)\cdot \left(5x^{2}+7\right)}}dx=-\frac{2\cdot \left(i\cdot \sqrt{35}-5\right)\cdot \sqrt{-\frac{5\cdot \left(x+1\right)}{i\cdot \sqrt{35}-5}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{i\cdot \sqrt{35}-5\cdot x}{i\cdot \sqrt{35}+5}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{i\cdot \sqrt{35}+5\cdot x}{i\cdot \sqrt{35}-5}}\cdot \mathrm{EllipticF}\! \left(\sqrt{-\frac{5\cdot \left(x+1\right)}{i\cdot \sqrt{35}-5}},\sqrt{-\frac{i\cdot \sqrt{35}-5}{i\cdot \sqrt{35}+5}}\right)}{5\cdot \sqrt{5\cdot x^{3}+5\cdot x^{2}+7\cdot x+7}}$$
$$I= F(1)-F(-1)=F(1)\approx 0.93818600923035115909$$
Verification:
$$\frac{d}{d x}F\! \left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5 x^{3}+5 x^{2}+7 x+7}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x+1\right) \left(5 x^{2}+7\right)}}$$
How to compute this result in Python?
import mpmath as mp

mp.mp.dps = 50
mp.mp.pretty = True

def elliptic_maple_f(z, k):
    """
    Elliptic integral of the first kind F(z,k) according to Maple definition.
    """
    return mp.ellipf(mp.asin(z), k**2)

def i_fun(x):
    """
    Elliptic integral
    """
    s35 = mp.sqrt(35)
    m5  = -5 + s35*1j
    p5  = +5 + s35*1j

    # Arguments for elliptic integral
    z   = mp.sqrt(-5*(x+1)/m5)
    k   = mp.sqrt(-m5/p5)

    numer = \
        mp.sqrt(-5*(x+1)/m5) * \
        mp.sqrt((-5*x+s35*1j)/p5) * \
        mp.sqrt((+5*x+s35*1j)/m5) * \
        elliptic_maple_f(z, k)

    denom = mp.sqrt((x+1)*(5*x**2+7))

    return -mp.mpf(2)/mp.mpf(5) * m5 * numer / denom

I = i_fun(mp.mpf(1))
print(f"I= {I}")

